# Camel synchronous route starts asynchronous route with recipientList

Tags: java, asynchronous, apache-camel, synchronous

Here is the begining of my route:

```
from("direct:initRoute").routeId("initRoute")
            .log("Start route")
            .beanRef("routeProcessor","extractProcessor")
            .validate().method("fileProcessor","valid")
            .beanRef("routeProcessor","initData")
            .beanRef("routeProcessor", "choiceSendTo")
            .recipientList(header("sendTo"));
```

Then other routes are started depending the data present in the `Exchange`.

I am calling this route **synchronously** like this:

```
ProducerTemplate template = camelContext.createProducerTemplate();
ExchangeBuilder exchangeBuilder = new ExchangeBuilder(camelContext);
// Code that setup the exchange.
LOGGER.error("BEFORE");
template.send("direct:initTraitement", exchangeBuilder.build());            
LOGGER.error("AFTER");
```

I expect the following oputputs in my logs:

```
- BEFORE
- DATA INIT LOGS
- AFTER
- **RECIPIENTS ROUTES LOGS**
```

But instead I've got this:

```
- BEFORE
- DATA INIT LOGS
- **RECIPIENTS ROUTES LOGS**
- AFTER
```

I thought routes were independents, so if I synchronously sent a request to a route, I would get the reply right after that route was completed. But apparently, the whole process (all connected routes) are executed before my the rest of the codes is ran.

I want that my codes continue to be executed just after `recipientList()` is called. How can I achieve this?

I tried to use `parallelProcessing()` after `recipientList()` as explained in the [documentation](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html) but it doesn't fix my problem.

EDIT: I need to start the first route synchronously. The code must run only when the `initData` function finished it's job. The following routes should be asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

parallelProcessing just means that if you give more than one endpoint to the recipientlist these endpoints will be processed in parallel. See documentation to parallelProcessing:

> Camel 2.2: If enabled, messages are sent to the recipients
>   concurrently. **Note that the calling thread will still wait until all
>   messages have been fully processed before it continues**; it's the
>   sending and processing of replies from recipients which happens in
>   parallel.

If you want to execute a route with the producerTemplate and don't want to wait until the route has finished you have to use for example the asynSend-method not the send-method.

Another possibility to is to ensure that the sendTo header is configured with asynchronous endpoints like seda.

More information is provided by the camel documentation, for example http://camel.apache.org/asynchronous-processing.html

kind regards,
soilworker

Comment: Or use the wire tap eip

Comment: Configuring the endpoints to be asynchrones was the correct solution for my problem. I didn't know the `SEDA` component, thanks.